# rebar generate error

Tags: erlang, rebar, build-tools

I'm attempting to use `rebar` to generate a node, and I've followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/basho/rebar/wiki/Release-handling).

Running `rebar get-deps compile` works fine, but running `rebar generate` gives me

```
ERROR: Unable to generate spec: read file info /home/inaimathi/common/rebar.config~ failed
ERROR: Unexpected error: rebar_abort
ERROR: generate failed while processing /home/inaimathi/common/rel: rebar_abort
```

Odd, given that `rebar.config~` shouldn't figure anywhere in the `generate` process. Removing `rebar.config~` and trying again gives me the same error, but relating to `rebar.config` instead.

My `rebar.config` looks like

```
{sub_dirs, ["rel"]}.
{lib_dirs, ["deps"]}.
{deps, [{erlsha2, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/vinoski/erlsha2.git", "HEAD"}}]}.
```

and my `reltool.config` looks like

```
{sys, [
       {lib_dirs, []},
       {erts, [{mod_cond, derived}, {app_file, strip}]},
       {app_file, strip},
       {rel, "common", "1",
        [
         kernel,
         stdlib,
         sasl,
         common
        ]},
       {rel, "start_clean", "",
        [
         kernel,
         stdlib
        ]},
       {boot_rel, "common"},
       {profile, embedded},
       {incl_cond, derived},
       {mod_cond, derived},
       {excl_archive_filters, [".*"]}, %% Do not archive built libs
       {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/.*", "^erts.*/bin/(dialyzer|typer)",
                           "^erts.*/(doc|info|include|lib|man|src)"]},
       {excl_app_filters, ["\.gitignore"]},
       {app, common, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}, {lib_dir, ".."}]}
      ]}.

{target_dir, "common"}.

{overlay, [
           {mkdir, "log/sasl"},
           {copy, "files/erl", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/erl"},
           {copy, "files/nodetool", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/nodetool"},
           {copy, "files/common", "bin/common"},
           {copy, "files/common.cmd", "bin/common.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/start_erl.cmd", "bin/start_erl.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/install_upgrade.escript", "bin/install_upgrade.escript"},
           {copy, "files/sys.config", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/sys.config"},
           {copy, "files/vm.args", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/vm.args"}
          ]}.
```

(entirely `rebar`-generated except that I had to add `{lib_dir, ".."}` as per the instructions I linked).

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:** I should mention the basics, given that I have no idea what's going wrong. Erlang R15B01 out of the Debian Wheezy repo running on a 64-bit core i3. I did a manual pull and build of rebar from [the basho repo](https://github.com/basho/rebar/). Not sure if anything else is relevant.

**EDIT2:** The same thing happens with the pre-built version of rebar found at https://github.com/downloads/basho/rebar/rebar

Comment: Did you ever find out an answer? I'm stuck on the same thing.

Comment: @ThomasKobberPanum - Nope. The deployment tool errors are the main reason I no longer use Erlang. Sorry, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should have run the `rebar generate` command in the `rel` directory before this [issue](https://github.com/basho/rebar/issues/213), it is fixed now.